# seque is not blocking when reading from BlockingQueue

Tags: clojure

From the [documentation](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/seque), it seems like the following evaluated at the repl should block?

```
(take 1 (seque (java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.)))
```

Surely I'm missing something obvious?

Answer (score 2):

It is an error to not pass `seque` a sequence to work with (you can override the queue to use, but you still must pass a sequence). It could do anything it wants, given that you've passed it nonsense arguments. It happens to return an empty sequence, which IMO is not the best thing to do: it would be better to report an error, but as a consequence of whatever implementation decisions were made, this is what happens instead.

Edit: a commenter points out that a LinkedBlockingQueue *is* a sequence, because it is a j.u.Collection, which is seqable. So it's not exactly erroneous input, but a valid (empty) sequence from the point of view of `seque`. The LBQ, when asked for a sequential view of its contents, looks to see if it has any items; it doesn't, so it returns an empty sequence.

Comment: Looks like it's making an (empty) seq out of the queue, which it can do because LinkedBlockingQueue implements java.util.Collection.

Comment: @amalloy I'm not sure if I'm just being obtuse, but the doc string does not really say what `seque` is for.  "Creates a queued seq"?

Comment: That's an entirely different question, and I'm not going to answer it in the comments on this one. But I'd suggest reading past the first sentence, and looking around on google for `clojure "seque"`.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L5352) for `seque`, what I understand it does is create a new `LinkedBlockingQueue` and start consuming the sequence `s` using an agent. The agent is used so that the "copying" of elements from `s` to the created `LinkedBlockingQueue` is done asynchronously.

The documentation indicates that if the asynchronous copying from the original sequence to the intermediate `BlockingQueue` is done slower than the speed at which you consume the lazy sequence `seque` returns, it will block.

This is not obvious at all and I would interpret the same that you did reading the documentation for `seque`. I had to look the source to figure out what was happening.